# Functional Testing in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am new to JMeter and I wish to do a functional test on a website. I have added an HTTP request default and added a recorder and I successfully recorded my usecase. When I run the script it shows as executing in the view record table listener. There are a few errors along the way but the script does execute.

After the script terminates execution I logged into the website and the use-case has not got executed. I am confused as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [4 Things You Should Never Do with Your JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-never-do-your-jmeter-script) article:

> **2. Don’t run the script exactly as you recorded it**
>
> After recording your script, there is still some work to do before you run it. It’s necessary to correlate variables, parameterize and add elements, to faithfully simulate users.

1. First of all add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, most web applications use cookies for authentication and cookie support is a vital part of JMeter web test plan.
2. Record your test one more time and compare 2 recorded scripts. If there are differences - you will need to **correlate** the corresponding values, i.e. extract them from the previous response using one of JMeter's [Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and substitute recorded "hard-coded" values with the appropriate JMeter Variables
3. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your Test Plan and re-run your test scenario carefully inspecting request and response details. The fact that request is not failing doesn't necessarily mean the fact your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing as you might be hitting login page all the time and JMeter simply treats HTTP Status Code 200 as successful.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I am still trying to figure this out. I was able to pinpoint the problem based on your advice which happens to be that the login is failing with the error {"requestFailed":"400","redirectUrl":"https:\/\/www.ydaz.lk\/","error":"CSRF Token invalid"}. I am trying to extract the CSRF token through a regular expression but I can't seem to find where this CSRF token comes in the response I don't see it anywhere any of the HTTP request responses. Could you kindly give your advice, thanks

Comment: You need to **carefully** inspect all the parts of response as the token could be a part of the URL, a [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) or a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies). It might also be the case that it comes as a cookie but needs to be passed as a request parameter. See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) for more details.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I was able to find the CSRF token and I extracted the value successfully through a Regular Expression Extractor and I passed it as a parameter to the CSRF field and now the above issue no longer occurs.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Though my script executes successfully I am back to square one as my Usecase does not actually get executed in the Ecommerce site I am testing. My use case is that I am logging in as a user navigating to the personal information section and adding a mailing address.  My expectation is that when I run this JMeter script it should log in as that user and add a mail address. But when I log to the site after running the script I don't see any added address. Can you please be kind to render your advice to me here, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I was finally able to run the use case successfully today on the website I was testing. I am sincerely grateful for the advice you gave me above, Thanks a lot.